# Capability for allowing user to post own comments without moderation

Tags: comments, capabilities, user-access, user-roles, moderation

I work at a radio station that has several WP user roles -- for simplicity sake, let's say Admin, Programmer, Subscriber, in decreasing order of ability.

Currently, Admin users need to approve comments left by Programmer users. How do I auto-approve Programmer-level comments, without letting that user level administrate comments globally?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Role Approved Comment plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-approved-comment/
This plugin will allow any specified role to have their comments automatically approved.

Comment: I'll try that when I get home and accept this answer if it works (Don't see why it shouldn't). Thanks!

Comment: even if not you can still get the idea from the code.
glad I cloud help.

Comment: That worked! I had to manually add the capability (role_approved_comment) to each required role, but works like a charm otherwise! Thanks!

Comment: Glad to help...